# Hash of a cell text in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-search-api

How can I compute a MD5 or SHA1 hash of text in a specific cell and set it to another cell in Google Spreadsheet?

Is there a formula like `=ComputeMD5(A1)` or `=ComputeSHA1(A1)`?

Or is it possible to write custom formula for this? How?

Answer (score 127):

Open `Tools > Script Editor` then paste the following code:

```javascript
function MD5 (input) {
  var rawHash = Utilities.computeDigest(Utilities.DigestAlgorithm.MD5, input);
  var txtHash = '';
  for (i = 0; i < rawHash.length; i++) {
    var hashVal = rawHash[i];
    if (hashVal < 0) {
      hashVal += 256;
    }
    if (hashVal.toString(16).length == 1) {
      txtHash += '0';
    }
    txtHash += hashVal.toString(16);
  }
  return txtHash;
}
```

Save the script after that and then use the `MD5()` function in your spreadsheet while referencing a cell.

This script is based on [Utilities.computeDigest()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#computedigestalgorithm-value) function.

Comment: Nice answer. You might want to add `Utilities.sleep(100)` somewhere inside the function, to prevent it from crashing when using the autofill function (otherwise you will run into a limit on how often a function can be called)

Comment: I can't seem to get this to match what `md5sum(1)` does; for example `frew` in the cli gives `c241183cbf6766bd86061a60d6c8fe1b` with no newline, but `cfb5d06a43aad502d0f6219143ba0e34` from the function.

Comment: This is really helpful. Seems like the line `hashVal += 256` should read `hashVal += 128` though. Utlities.computeDigest() returns a byte array. The bytes are represented as integers ranging from -128 to 127. Adding 128 will convert them to numbers between 0 and 256.

Comment: I'd add Charset UTF8 to the digest computation. `Utilities.computeDigest(Utilities.DigestAlgorithm.MD5, input, Utilities.Charset.UTF_8);`

Comment: update: `Extensions > Apps Script`

Answer (score 22):

Thanks to gabhubert for the code.

This is the SHA1 version of that code (very simple change)

```javascript
function GetSHA1(input) {
  var rawHash = Utilities.computeDigest(Utilities.DigestAlgorithm.SHA_1, input);
  var txtHash = '';
  for (j = 0; j <rawHash.length; j++) {
    var hashVal = rawHash[j];
    if (hashVal < 0)
      hashVal += 256; 
    if (hashVal.toString(16).length == 1)
     txtHash += "0";
    txtHash += hashVal.toString(16);
    }
  return txtHash;
}
```

Comment: This failed for me, until i added var j to the loop. Maybe I made a mistake, maybe the google is stricter now than when this was written.

Comment: My final valid solution: https://jsfiddle.net/alexander_js_developer/gmx2f08o/

Answer (score 6):

Ok, got it,

Need to create custom function as explained in
http://code.google.com/googleapps/appsscript/articles/custom_function.html

And then use the apis as explained in
http://code.google.com/googleapps/appsscript/service_utilities.html

I need to handtype the complete function name so that I can see the result in the cell.

Following is the sample of the code that gave base 64 encoded hash of the text

```
function getBase64EncodedMD5(text)
{ 
  return Utilities.base64Encode( Utilities.computeDigest(Utilities.DigestAlgorithm.MD5, text));
}
```

Comment: Base64 is not a hash in any meaningful sense of the term. It's a numbering system conversion.

Answer (score 3):

The difference between this solution and the others is:

1. It fixes an issue some of the above solution have with offsetting the output of `Utilities.computeDigest` (it offsets by 128 instead of 256)
2. It fixes an issue that causes some other solutions to produce the same hash for different inputs by calling `JSON.stringify()` on `input` before passing it to `Utilities.computeDigest()`

```js
function MD5(input) {
  var result = "";
  var byteArray = Utilities.computeDigest(Utilities.DigestAlgorithm.MD5, JSON.stringify(input));
  for (i=0; i < byteArray.length; i++) {
    result += (byteArray[i] + 128).toString(16) + "-";
  }
  result = result.substring(result, result.length - 1); // remove trailing dash
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

to get hashes for a range of cells, add this next to gabhubert's function:

```
function RangeGetMD5Hash(input) {
  if (input.map) {            // Test whether input is an array.
    return input.map(GetMD5Hash); // Recurse over array if so.
  } else {
    return GetMD5Hash(input)
  }
}
```

and use it in cell this way:

```
=RangeGetMD5Hash(A5:X25)
```

It returns range of same dimensions as source one, values will spread down and right from cell with formulae.

It's universal single-value-function to range-func conversion method ([ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#optimization)), and it's way faster than separate formuleas for each cell; in this form, it also works for single cell, so maybe it's worth to rewrite source function this way.

Answer (score 2):

Based on @gabhubert but using array operations to get the hexadecimal representation

```js
function sha(str){
    return Utilities
      .computeDigest(Utilities.DigestAlgorithm.SHA_1, str) // string to digested array of integers
      .map(function(val) {return val<0? val+256 : val}) // correct the offset
      .map(function(val) {return ("00" + val.toString(16)).slice(-2)}) // add padding and enconde
      .join(''); // join in a single string
}
```

Comment: Utilities.computeDigest(Utilities.DigestAlgorithm.MD5, "thisisteststring")
  .map(function(chr){return (chr+256).toString(16).slice(-2)})
  .join('')

Answer (score 1):

Using @gabhubert answer, you could do this, if you want to get the results from a whole row. From the script editor.

```
function GetMD5Hash(value) {
  var rawHash = Utilities.computeDigest(Utilities.DigestAlgorithm.MD5, value);
  var txtHash = '';
    for (j = 0; j <rawHash.length; j++) {
   var hashVal = rawHash[j];
    if (hashVal < 0)
      hashVal += 256; 
    if (hashVal.toString(16).length == 1)
      txtHash += "0";
    txtHash += hashVal.toString(16);
  }
    return txtHash;
}

function straightToText() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
  var r = 1;
  var n_rows = 9999;
  var n_cols = 1;
  var column = 1;
  var sheet = ss[0].getRange(r, column, n_rows, ncols).getValues(); // get first sheet, a1:a9999
  var results = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < sheet.length; i++) {
    var hashmd5= GetMD5Hash(sheet[i][0]);
    results.push(hashmd5);
  }
  var dest_col = 3;
  for (var j = 0; j < results.length; j++) {
    var row = j+1;
    ss[0].getRange(row, dest_col).setValue(results[j]);  // write output to c1:c9999 as text
  }  
}
```

And then, from the Run menu, just run the function straightToText() so you can get your result, and elude the too many calls to a function error.

Comment: foretasteing you to look at my answer for doing this

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for an option that would provide a shorter result. What do you think about this? It only returns 4 characters. The unfortunate part is that it uses i's and o's which can be confused for L's and 0's respectively; with the right font and in caps it wouldn't matter much.

```
function getShortMD5Hash(input) {
  var rawHash = Utilities.computeDigest(Utilities.DigestAlgorithm.MD5, input);
  var txtHash = '';
    for (j = 0; j < 16; j += 8) { 
    hashVal = (rawHash[j] + rawHash[j+1] + rawHash[j+2] + rawHash[j+3]) ^ (rawHash[j+4] + rawHash[j+5] + rawHash[j+6] + rawHash[j+7])
    if (hashVal < 0)
      hashVal += 1024;
    if (hashVal.toString(36).length == 1)
      txtHash += "0";
    txtHash += hashVal.toString(36);
  }
    return txtHash.toUpperCase();
  }
```

Comment: I don't understand the utility of a 4 byte hash.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to get a hash across a range of cells, so I run it like this:

```html
function RangeSHA256(input)
{
    return Array.isArray(input) ?
        input.map(row => row.map(cell => SHA256(cell))) :
        SHA256(input);
}
```