# hashing a cell in Google Spreadsheet. I have zero experience in this

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have followed [a question answered in one of the links in StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7994410/hash-of-a-cell-text-in-google-spreadsheet). I have copied this code and save it. But I really have no idea how to run this code to hash my cells ranging from A2:F2360.

I have no idea how to hash them still.

Also, the code you see below, I tried clicking on RUN but it keep says:

> Exception: Argument cannot be null: value
> MD5 @ Code.gs:2

what should I key on what cell, please?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You are executing the function without any parameters, thus your 2nd line errors out as you don't have `input` for it.

If you wish to hash all non-empty cells in `A2:F2360` which is located in `Sheet1`, you need to first access those cells, read their values, modify them using the `MD5` function, and write it back again. See code below.

#### Script:

```
// function that will hash the values
function MD5 (input) {
  var rawHash = Utilities.computeDigest(Utilities.DigestAlgorithm.MD5, input);
  var txtHash = '';
  for (i = 0; i < rawHash.length; i++) {
    var hashVal = rawHash[i];
    if (hashVal < 0) {
      hashVal += 256;
    }
    if (hashVal.toString(16).length == 1) {
      txtHash += '0';
    }
    txtHash += hashVal.toString(16);
  }
  return txtHash;
}

// main function that will call your MD5 function
// execute this one instead of MD5
function main() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  // access the values of the sheet name indicated
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  // access the values of the range indicated
  var range = sheet.getRange('A2:F2360');
  // get the values in the mentioned range
  var values = range.getValues();

  // modify each cell to be hashed using MD5 function above.
  // added a condition where it won't write anything for blank cells as MD5 still hashes blank string
  var output = values.map(row => row.map(cell => cell ? MD5(cell) : cell));

  // write the modified values to the same range
  range.setValues(output);
}
```

#### Sample data:

[image: sample]

#### Output:

[image: output]

#### Note:

- If you are unfamiliar with Apps Script, read more about it on the references listed but not limited to:

#### References:

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/tutorials
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets
- https://courses.benlcollins.com/p/apps-script-blastoff